# mycheckbox.setSelected(false) has no effect

Tags: android, checkbox, selectall

I have columns of checkboxes, the top row of which are CheckAll checkboxes for that particular column. If I uncheck the Checkall from the first CheckAll checkbox in the leftmost column I would like to uncheck the remaining CheckAll checkboxes.

However the `mycheckbox.setSelected(false)` has no effect.  If however, I do a `mycheckbox.setEnabled(false)` (just as a test) it DOES work and the checkbox is disabled.

By the way, this is a "header row" for a listview with a custom adapter.  The contents of the listview work as expected.

Any idea how to get the checkbox unchecked?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `mycheckbox.setChecked(false)` instead of `setSelected`.

I've tried searching for `setSelected` to see what it does, but in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) of the CheckBox, I was not able to find it (which suggested to me that this method is probably found in one of the **parent** classes of `CheckBox`). Tried typing it in Android Studio:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplication());
cb.setSelected(true);
```

Went to the implementation of the method (`CTRL+Click`) and saw this in the **TextView** class, from which almost every other widget is derived:

```
@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    boolean wasSelected = isSelected();

    super.setSelected(selected);

    if (selected != wasSelected && mEllipsize == TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE) {
        if (selected) {
            startMarquee();
        } else {
            stopMarquee();
        }
    }
}
```

> Interesting thing to note here is that `setChecked` method is contained in the `CompoundButton` class, while `setSelected` is is `TextView`. That means that `setSelected` does something completely different because textView surely cannot be checked/unchecked.

I hope this explains it well.

Comment: Whoops.  I must need some sleep.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, don't beat yourself up. It is a blunder, but the explanation behind it is not naive. `setSelected` is quite ambiguous in this context, to be fair.

Comment: omg so many years programming Android and I still got stuck in an error like this one hahahaha (shame) xD